# Combine sections into chapter. Each section a separate .tex file

Tags: bibtex, subdividing, include

I am putting together a portfolio of evidence together. I have written all the individual pieces of evidence as separate latex documents. Some of these documents have references at the end of the section some don't. All references are stored in a file `references.bib`.

Here is an example of a standalone piece of evidence ( I have removed the text body)

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fps@figure{!htb}
\setlength\@fptop{0pt} 
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.6}% before: .5 
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.15} % before: .2 
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.8}     % before: .7 
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.5}  % before: .3 
\setcounter{topnumber}{3} % before: 2 
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1} % before: 1 
\setcounter{totalnumber}{5} % before: 3 
%opening

\begin{document}

\section*{Assessing Progression in Whole Body Bone Scans}


\bibliography{/path_to/references.bib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

However I am having several issues when trying to combine the evidence into a single chapter. I have take the following approach. My Portfolio.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{dmathesis}
%% uncommand the following line to print equation labels next to
%% equation numbers. 

%% The following is to control the format of your thesis
\input{format}

%% File to be included while running latex.
\includeonly{CoveringReport,EvidenceA-D,EvidenceE}
\begin{document}

%% Front page of thesis
%\input{frontpage}

%% Main text
% set page number starts from 1
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{CoveringReport}
\include{EvidenceA-D}
\include{EvidenceE}
\end{document}
```

EvidenceA-D

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\chapter{Supplementary Evidence}

\section*{Evidence A: MSci Degree Certificate - Physics}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[page=3,scale=0.65,angle=0]{Images/Degrees.pdf}
\caption{MSci Physics Degree Certificate}
\end{figure}
\newpage

\section*{Evidence B: PhD Degree Certificate - Physics}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[page=2,scale=0.65, angle=0]{Images/Degrees.pdf}
\caption{PhD Degree Certificate}
\end{figure}
\newpage

\section*{Evidence C: MSc Degree Certificate - Medical Physics}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[page=1,scale=0.7]{Images/Degrees.pdf}
\caption{MSc Medical Physics: Degree Certificate}
\end{figure}

\section*{Evidence D: IPEM Postgraduate Diploma}

Evidence E
\section*{Evidence E: Assessing Progression in Whole Body Bone Scans}


\bibliography{/path_to/references.bib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

I would like to keep references to be at the end of each section. The first reference in each section should begin at [1].

I am having the following issues
(1) Each new piece of evidence starts on a new page. I have pretty tight page constraints and would like the next section to start at the next available space
(2) I get error messages
`Citation on page .. undefined` [This was fine in the standalone document]
`No Portfolio.bbl`
`There were undefined references`

How do I solve these issues?

I had seen a solution using biblatex and one large Evidence chapter.

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{refsection}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
```

However, I have a CentOS 6 operating system and have been unable to successfully implement such a solution as I cannot install biblatex and all its dependencies

EDIT

---

I have solve the first issue by using `\input` in place of `include`

Comment: Long story short: You want multiple bibliographies? Maybe this could help http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multbib